# How to pass uint32_t * as a property to QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to pass an of array of `uint32_t` to QML as a property of `uint32_t*`

```
Q_PROPERTY(uint32_t *Data READ Data WRITE setData NOTIFY DataChanged)
```

but I got an error

```
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'uint32_t*' for property 'mpk::mssc::gui::HistogramController::histogramData'
```

How can I pass `uint32_t*` to QML code using Q_PROPERTY?

Comment: Use [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) to understand the C++/QML type conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use a C array in QML. What you can do is create a QList from that array and expose it like a property. In that case you'll be able to treat it like a JS array.

```
Q_PROPERTY(QList<unsigned int> data READ data WRITE setData NOTIFY dataChanged)
```

Also note that you won't be able to get notifications for elements changing or of changes of the QList itself. To get notifications and use for bindings you'll have to reset the entire QList.

Another option would be to wrap your array with proper invokable methods:

```
Q_INVOKABLE unsigned int getElement(int i)
Q_INVOKABLE void setElement(int i, unsigned int val)
Q_INVOKABLE void appendElement(unsigned int val)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I guarantied 32 bit? Because 'int' depends on bitness of the operating system

Comment: From QML the only type you have is int: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-int.html. Apparently it is an int32_t, not a uint32_t. However it seems you can pass a quint32, but you have to store it with a generic "var" in QML.